# Making sure a value is equal to one of many in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable containing values like "ABC", "DEF", etc.

I'm trying to form a LINQ query where the value of a property in my object may be equal to one of the many values contained in my IEnumerable. How do I form that LINQ query?

```
var statesFilter = new List<string>();
statesFilter.Add("NY");
statesFilter.Add("CA");

var employees = new List<Employee>();
employees = getDataFromSomewhere();

// Code below is not working. Just wanted to give you an idea about my LINQ query
var myFilteredList = employees.Where(x => x.State.Contains(statesFilter));
```

Employee class could be something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `Employee` class?

Comment: You just need to rearrange the predicate in the WHERE clause to a.Where(statesFilter.Contains(x.State))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `State` property is of type string, you should change your `Where` to the following:

```
var myFilteredList = employees.Where(x => statesFilter.Contains(x.State));
```

Also, you can do this:

```
var myFilteredList = employees.Where(x => statesFilter.Any(s=>s==x.State));
```

Answer (score 1):

Condition should be

```
x=>statesFilter.Contains(x.State))
```